# Cypher query for matching on datetime property of relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph with the following schema.

```
(a:Person)-[:MET {at:meeting_datetime}]-(b:Person)
```

There could be multiple `MET` Relationships between `(a)` and `(b)`. I need to find subgraphs of my graph where all persons met at closely following times (one hour). One approach would be to use

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[a_b_met]-(b:Person)
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(a, {
    relationshipFilter: "MET",
    minLevel: 1
    
})
YIELD nodes, relationships
WITH nodes, relationships
UNWIND relationships as relationship
WITH relationship
MATCH (a)-[relationship]-(b)
WHERE duration.between(relationship.at, a_b_met.at).months = 0 
AND duration.between(relationship.at, a_b_met.at).days = 0 
AND abs(duration.between(relationship.at, a_b_met.at).seconds) < 3600
RETURN a,b
```

But this would be expensive in terms of computation as I would match all possible `MET` paths before filtering them with the `at` property. Is there a better way?

Edit: Above code doesn't work as `a_b_met` is not defined for the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: How big is your graph

Comment: Say about 100 Persons and 500000 METs

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
    MATCH path = (a:Person)-[:MET*]-(b:Person) 
    WHERE duration.between(apoc.coll.max([rel in relationships(path)| rel.at]), apoc.coll.min([rel in relationships(path)| rel.at])).days = 0
    AND 
    duration.between(apoc.coll.max([rel in relationships(path)| rel.at]), apoc.coll.min([rel in relationships(path)| rel.at])).months = 0 
    AND 
    duration.between(apoc.coll.max([rel in relationships(path)| rel.at]), apoc.coll.min([rel in relationships(path)| rel.at])).seconds < 3600
    RETURN path
```

It is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this works reasonably. But now I have an upper limit on how many persons meeting at roughly the same time I can track.

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[a_b_met:MET]-(b:Person) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (b)-[b_c_met:MET]-(c:Person)
WHERE duration.between(b_c_met.at, a_b_met.at).days = 0 AND duration.between(b_c_met.at, a_b_met.at).months = 0 AND abs(duration.between(b_c_met.at, a_b_met.at).seconds) < 3600 AND c<>a
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[c_d_met:MET]-(d:Person)
WHERE duration.between(c_d_met.at, a_b_met.at).days = 0 AND duration.between(c_d_met.at, a_b_met.at).months = 0 AND abs(duration.between(c_d_met.at, a_b_met.at).seconds) < 3600 AND d<>a AND d<>b
RETURN a,a_b_met,b,b_c_met,c,c_d_met,d
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the representation of the time to be a single number and then this gave some reasonable results:

```
MATCH path = (a:Person)-[:MET*]->(b:Person)
WHERE a<>b AND length(path)>1 AND apoc.coll.max([rel in relationships(path)| rel.at]) - apoc.coll.min([rel in relationships(path)| rel.at]) < 3600
RETURN ([nd in nodes(path)|nd.name])
```

Comment: Thanks. I was also thinking rather than comparing the days, months and seconds of “duration”, it will be simpler to compare its epochSeconds property. That’s basically what you are also doing by treating time as a number. I will try this.